# Spark Java sum is giving incorrect value

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-java

Spark Java sum is giving incorrect value

Java sample code is as below

```
List<Double> points = Arrays.asList(-6221.4, 6380.46);
Dataset<Row> dt  = spark.createDataset(points, Encoders.DOUBLE()).toDF("double_vals");
dt.createOrReplaceTempView("dual_table");
spark.sql("select sum(double_vals) from dual_table").show(false);
```

The expect result is 159.06 but the result I am getting is as below

```
+-----------------+
|sum(double_vals) |
+-----------------+
|159.0600000000004|
+-----------------+
```

Am I doing something wrong ?

Extending the example , what if the decimal is dynamic after sum as below, I will not be able to restrict it to 2 decimal points, is there any solution ?

```
Tuple3<String,String,Double> val1 = new Tuple3<>("Day1","Ram", -6221.4);
Tuple3<String,String,Double> val2 = new Tuple3<>("Day2","Ram", 6380.46);
Tuple3<String,String,Double> val3 = new Tuple3<>("Day1","Sam", 380.46);
Tuple3<String,String,Double> val4 = new Tuple3<>("Day2","Sam", 6380.462);
List<Tuple3<String,String,Double>> points = Arrays.asList(val1,val2,val3,val4);

Dataset<Row> dt  = spark.createDataset(points, Encoders.tuple(Encoders.STRING(),Encoders.STRING(),Encoders.DOUBLE())).toDF("day","name","profit");

dt.createOrReplaceTempView("dual_table");

Dataset<Row> newDs = spark.sql("select NAME, sum(profit) sum_val from dual_table group by name");

newDs.show();
```

Result will be

```
+----+------------------+
|NAME|           sum_val|
+----+------------------+
| Ram| 159.0600000000004| This needs 2 decimal points 
| Sam|6760.9220000000005| This needs 3 decimal points
+----+------------------+
```

Comment: Yes, It is expected. if you want you can use `round` function to get your expected results.

Comment: Welcome to the vast world of floating-point arithmetic, where the expression `0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3` is false (try it in Python, Java, ...). 
In short, if a number is stored on 64 bits, at most 2^{64} different numbers can be represented. However there is an infinite amount of real number in math, and so many of them are represented as an approximation, which leads to inaccuracy errors such as the one you found.
Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic for an introduction to the subject

Answer (score 1):

Use `round` function to truncate precision

```
spark.sql("select round(sum(double_vals), 2) as sum_value from dual_table").show(false)

+---------+
|sum_value|
+---------+
|159.06   |
+---------+
```

Use `cast( sum(<column name>) AS decimal(10, 2))`

```
spark.sql("select cast(sum(double_vals) as decimal(10, 2)) as sum_value from dual_table").show(false)

+---------+
|sum_value|
+---------+
|159.06   |
+---------+
```

Comment: It is a bad practice to round the result if it is going to be used for intermediate calculation. If you do so, that would only amplify floating-point arithmetic errors.
It is only acceptable to do so in the presentation layer of your application, in order to convert the number to a human-friendly format, with the number of digits adapted to the precision of your inputs

Comment: This will not work if we are using sum function on a column with group by,  as the number of decimal digits changes after aggregation  Ex : 238.98355, 34.33, -263.4